# How connect Two tables that connect the information about Address?

Tags: database

I have One table ,reduce the redunduncy i devided into two parts 
Table
Email Address(PK)
Name
city 
state
Pincode
Country
Land_Line_No
D_O_B
Gender
Marital_Status

After Devided

Table1
Name
city 
Land_Line_No
D_O_B
Gender
Marital_Status

Table2
city 
state
Pincode
Country

My question is how to connect this two table

Answer (score 0):

An attribute in the second table would be same as the primary key in the first table. These attributes are commonly known as foreign key.

On another issue however, what have you reduced? 
You have city in both the tables which looks redundant. Perhaps I am not clear as to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Schema should look more like this:

```
Table1 Name municipalityID Land_Line_No D_O_B Gender Marital_Status 
Table2 municipalityID city state Pincode Country
```

Now the `municipalityID` field in Table2 should be unique on each line thus making it the primary key of the table. In order to associate any record form Table with a specific city, etc.. you would reference the proper `municipalityID` (this is a foreign key in Table1 referencing Table2).